# How and why we use CNN layer wrapped with time distributed layer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word-embedding, faster-rcnn

I need to know how this code works.  It's taking Embedding then it sends it into this model. model1 is CNN and moel2 is Time distributed layer. Why wrapping is done in this code, i didn't find article on this.

```py
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Embedding(nb_words + 1,
                     embedding_dim,
                     weights = [word_embedding_matrix],
                     input_length = max_sentence_len,
                     trainable = False))

model1.add(Convolution1D(filters = nb_filter, 
                         kernel_size = filter_length, 
                         padding = 'same'))
model1.add(BatchNormalization())
model1.add(Activation('relu'))
model1.add(Dropout(dropout))

model1.add(Convolution1D(filters = nb_filter, 
                         kernel_size = filter_length, 
                         padding = 'same'))
model1.add(BatchNormalization())
model1.add(Activation('relu'))
model1.add(Dropout(dropout))

model1.add(Flatten())



model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Embedding(nb_words + 1,
                     embedding_dim,
                     weights = [word_embedding_matrix],
                     input_length = max_sentence_len,
                     trainable = False))

model2.add(Convolution1D(filters = nb_filter, 
                         kernel_size = filter_length, 
                         padding = 'same'))
model2.add(BatchNormalization())
model2.add(Activation('relu'))
model2.add(Dropout(dropout))

model2.add(Convolution1D(filters = nb_filter, 
                         kernel_size = filter_length, 
                         padding = 'same'))
model2.add(BatchNormalization())
model2.add(Activation('relu'))
model2.add(Dropout(dropout))

model2.add(Flatten())
```

then  it merges and getting the output. I don't understand the computation behind this.

Comment: here is the whole code https://github.com/Currie32/Predicting-Similar-Questions/blob/master/predicting_duplicate_questions_competition.ipynb

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do not use the comments space for such additional information - edit & update your post instead.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "moel2 is Time distributed layer". model1 and model2 in your example are identical. From quickly browsing though the github link it seems that these are used to build a Siamese  Network where you can input two embeddings (of questions in this case) and output if they are equivalent (the same question worded differently) or not.